# Migrating a plone site to dot net

Tags: .net, plone

We have a Plone site whose data is stored in PostGresql using Relstorage. Now we are looking to migrate the site to Dot Net.

My question is: how can we migrate data from the Plone site to sql server so it can be used by the dot net application.

Answer (score 2):

Write a Python script to export the data from Plone into whatever format you like for import into dot net. E.g.:

```
# my_script.py
items = app.Plone.portal_catalog()
for item in items:
    obj = item.getObject()
    print "Migrating %s" obj.Title()
    # Do stuff with obj
```

Run the script via:

```
$ bin/instance run my_script.py
```

Answer (score 0):

For Archetypes based contet you can [use ore.contentmirror](http://code.google.com/p/contentmirror/), for Dexterity content types there is new plugin [collective.dexteritycontentmirror](https://github.com/lck/collective.dexteritycontentmirror) (it was forked from ore.contenmirror with same features but supporting Dexterity content types). Both products can be used to mirror the entire Plone site into relational database. ore.contentmirror has excellent documentation which can be applied also to collective.dexteritycontentmirror